# Searching for line that starts with a or b and ends in a digit

Tags: unix

I'm not sure how to combine the code for searching for a line that starts with a or b and ends in a digit. 
This is the first part.

```
 grep ^[ab]
```

Second part

```
 grep [0-9]$
```

How do I combine both into one line of code?

Comment: please edit your question to include test data about what should match, and what doesn't matter. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can match anything that is between:

```
grep '^[ab].*[0-9]$'
```

Comment: Ah I see so the * indicates that anything that ends with [0-9].

Comment: No. `*` means 0 or more repetitions of previous character. In this case `.` which has special meaning - any character.